# Stuck with SQL query need guidance

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I am a beginner in learning SQL can anyone help me making a SQL Query:

two tales:

**users** two columns:

- id the unique user id
- car owned the user

**cars**

- car is the unique car name
- garage who service the car

I need a select statement that return two columns  id and garage considering of user id and the garage name where their car go for service . If a user's car is missing from cars table , the garage column should contain "Missing" instead. return the table sorted by user id's

Users table

```
id  car
1   Lamborghini Diablo
2   Ford Raptor
3   Ferrari Testarossa
4   Porsche 911 Carrera
5   Jensen Interceptor
```

Cars table

```
Car                      Garage
Lamborghini Diablo      Auto Tek
Porsche 911 Carrera     Auto Tek
Ferrari Testarossa      Automotive Depot
Ford Raptor             Dentworks
```

output:

```
1   Auto Tek
2   Dentworks
3   Automotive Depot
4   Auto Tek
5   Missing
```

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a left anti-join here:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    COALESCE(c.Garage, 'Missing') AS Garage
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Cars c
    ON c.Car = u.car;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thankyou for the query i was not aware of COALESCE SQL function thank you for your help now its increased my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
select users.id, coalesce(cars.garage, 'Missing')
from Users
left join Car
  on users.car = cars.Car
```

Comment: you need a left join.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try :

SELECT
u.id,
ISNULL(c.Garage, 'Missing') AS Garage
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Cars c
ON c.Car = u.car;

you can see the difference between COALESCE and ISNULL in this article :
https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/coalesce-vs-isnull